# Ho do I remove a listbox new item placeholder?

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have been scratching my head for a while with an extra item in a wrap panel for content in a ListBox.

I finally striped back my code and discovered the LixtBox itself has a New Item Placeholder at the end of the data I have bound to it.

I haven't been able to figure out how to disable the New Item Placeholder. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

After some more searching i discovered that the data source was being affected by a DataGrid. Within the same screen I am displaying detailed data in a DataGrid and also summary data in a ListBox.

We don't allow users to add items to the DataGrid so after I set the DataGrid's CanUserAddRows="False" my problem went away.